# Mirror text input to another input in a forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the view below, i display input (Enter your phone number) upon every question that is listed like below.

Now when i type into the first phone input box, how can i mirror the exact text in the subsequent phone input boxes below with Jquery or javascript in the for-loop?

```
..Enter your phone...........      

1. Question 1 

....Enter your phone.............

2. Question 2



 @forelse ($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="phone" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[phone]">
                            <label for="phone">Enter Your Phone Number</label>
                  </div>
                          <br>
                    <p class="flow-text">Question {{ $key+1 }} - {{ $question->title }}</p>
                        @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                          <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="answer" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]">
                            <label for="answer">Answer</label>
                          </div>
          @endif
          @endforeach
```

**What i want**

When i type 050 in the first input box for phone, it should duplicate the same for the any other input box with name `phone`.

Comment: what will you need and share your output...?

Comment: @Bhargav, mirror input into another input..check update

Comment: For every question you have an input field for the phonenumber with the same id "phone". Doesn't this cause an error?

Comment: `forelse` ..? There's no JS in the question ..? Just listen to input event of the input to mirror, and in that handler copy the value from the original.

Comment: If you want to request the same number via each field, then why do you have more than one such field to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach ($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="phone{{$question->id}}" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[phone]" class="phone">
                            <label for="phone{{$question->id}}">Enter Your Phone Number</label>
                  </div>
                          <br>
                    <p class="flow-text">Question {{ $key+1 }} - {{ $question->title }}</p>
                        @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                          <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="answer{{$question->id}}" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]">
                            <label for="answer{{$question->id}}">Answer</label>
                          </div>
          @endif
          @endforeach
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".phone").on("change keyup paste",function(){
    $(".phone").not(this).val($(this).val());
 });
});
```

**Tip 1**
Never give same id to multiple elements in forloop always use unique key to attach with id.

**Solution**
Give same class phone in your loop. Using jQuery check if the value is changed or not. If changed set that value for all input with same class.

Comment: Yes sure this is just an example of code which can be used for reference and can be modified by OP according to the requirements. @Teemu